# Es posible invocar un metodo de una super clase desde el eventon onClick?

Tags: java, android, herencia

Resulta que tengo un boton que realiza una accion con un if pero resulta que si no entra a ese if necesito que se ejecuten un metodo de una clase de android que son los que ponen el menu en el action bar:

```
btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(primerNombre.getText().toString().trim())){
                customToadError(getApplicationContext(),"Debe ingresar al menos un criterio de búsqueda");
            }else{
             // aqui deberian ejecutarse los metodos de sobreescritos que pondrian una opcion

            }
        }
    });
```

estos son los metodos sobre escritos:

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_agregar) {
       Intent i=new Intent(ListSrActivity.this, NuevoSRActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Que método querés llamar y desde dónde?

Comment: los metodos sobreescritos

Comment: pero esos son métodos del menú. Podriás llamar directamente a la Activity que quieres ir: else{ Intent ...

Answer (score 0):

El método `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` lo llama Android directamente para armar el menú del toolbar o action bar.

En cuanto al segundo método, en lugar de tratar de ejecutar la acción emulando el botón, directamente invocá la acción a ejecutar:

Por ejemplo:

```
btnBuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(primerNombre.getText().toString().trim())){
                customToadError(getApplicationContext(),"Debe ingresar al menos un criterio de búsqueda");
            }else{
             // aqui deberian ejecutarse los metodos de sobreescritos que pondrian una opcion
                iniciarNuevoSRActivity();
            }
        }
    });


public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_agregar) {
       iniciarNuevoSRActivity();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void iniciarNuevoSRActivity(){
    Intent i=new Intent(ListSrActivity.this, NuevoSRActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```